# ODATA (8.0.0-RC) The query specified in the URI is not valid. The property 'Id' cannot be used in the $filter query option

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

Did they change the behavior again? A very simple setup is not working:

```
services.AddOData(opt =>
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Tenant>("tenants").EntityType.HasKey(t => t.Id);  
    opt.AddModel(builder.GetEdmModel())
    opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(25);
});
```

I can't $filter on any properties, $orderby on any properties, etc. Same message for any property:

```
The property '<any property>' cannot be used in the <$filter|$orderby> query option.
```

Also, although I `.SetMaxTop(25)`, I get the following:

```
The limit of '0' for Top query has been exceeded. The value from the incoming request is '10'.
```

I've compared my code to the [sample](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/master/sample/ODataRoutingSample) and didn't think I was missing anything.

Comment: Any resolution for this issue? i am in.Net 6, way  has been changed. using EnableQueryAttribute its done. But i am facing same issue , although i am passing  MaxTop = 100